# Jquery working very slow in IE6

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jquery code in my application..

the idea is to click a button when the user comes of a form and clicks any button on the screen..

```
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form').focusin(function() {
                $(this).addClass('focused');
            });
            $(':not(form)').bind('click', function(e) {
                if (!$(e.target).parents('form.focused').length) {
                    form.getElementById("customerdetails").click();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

this script works fine in forefox but this is extremely slow in IE6...may i know the reason for this?? does it work faster in IE8...any ideas??

please suggest to improve this in IE6

many thanks in advance,
Jack.

Comment: Hi, "the idea is to click a button when the user comes of a form and clicks any button on the screen.." this makes no sense. Can you clarify.

Comment: what is the `form` variable that you use here- `form.getElementById("customerdetails").click()`?

Comment: What exactly is slow. The initialization phase or the click itself? If it's initialization, `$(':not(form)').bind('click', ` is probably your slowdown.

Comment: I'm not sure this will solve your problem, but put your markup through a validator: http://validator.w3.org/ and fix where necessary. Invalid markup *might* be the reason that your script is sluggish in IE6.

Comment: I hope it will work in IE8, Because some of the functionalities which does not support Jquery in IE6.. or best solution is instead of using Id values try to use the class names.. let me know how it goes..

Comment: Hi Redsqure, this is jsf based application and i have two forms.. the requirement is if the enter details in my botton form and navigate to somewhere using the buttons within the top form ,, the details should be saved..
i am not using 'click' but i am using 'button'..does this makes sense? - thanks , jack

Comment: Hi pekka, i am triggering two events on a single button click.. one is original button action within the form and the other is clicking event in another form through jquery..looks like one of these event triggers is slow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `$(':not(form)').bind('click', ...)` will loop through every element in the document except the `<form>` tags and add a separate click handler to each one.
This can be extremely slow.

Instead, you should add a single `click` handler to the document and check whether the click originated inside a `<form>` tag, like this:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.is('form.focused') || $target.closest('form.focused').length)
        return;

    form.getElementById("customerdetails").click();
});
```

Comment: Hi SLaks, I am performing two actions on a single button. One through jsf action and other through jquery(above code) on that. the jsf action is getting triggered first...i want my jquery code to be trigger first.. how can i achive this? please suggest...basically jsf code is overriding some of the functionality i need in jquery call..if my jquery gets executed first...i can avoid the issue..

Comment: @Jack: You need to run the jQuery code after the server replies.  For more details, ask a separate question and show us your code.

Answer (score 7):

```
$(':not(form)').bind()
```

Ouch! You just selected *every element* on the page except for forms, and added a `click` handler on each one separately. That's probably a whole load of elements (even things like `<head>` and `<script>` for which `click` makes no sense).

This will indeed be slow—everywhere: you only don't see it in the other browsers because their JS engines are faster than IE6 in general.

Use delegation on a parent element to catch all clicks from below it, checking the selector condition on each click rather than selecting all the elements and altering them:

```
$(document).delegate('*', 'click', function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('form.focused *'))
        $('#customerdetails').focus();
});
```

[edit: moved selector test; whilst delegating on `:not(form.focused *)` does work in jQuery, it's slightly naughty in that it's not a standard CSS3 selector. CSS3 only allows a ‘simple selector’ in `:not`.]

Comment: Hi, i am not using click, sorry..i am using suubmit..

<script> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('form').focusin(function() {
                $(this).addClass('focused');
            });
            $(':not(form)').bind('submit', function(e) {
                if (!$(e.target).parents('form.focused').length) {
                    form.getElementById("customerdetails").click();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: even then it is very slow..i have tested in IE8, still this is sloe..but slightly better than IE6.. i assume i am triggering two actions, one direct submit and the other through jquery on a single button..

please suggest how i can improve the speed...many thanks, jack.

Comment: Er, what? You're binding `submit` only on elements that *aren't* `<form>`, which is the only element that supports the `submit` event? What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use **[delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** to attach one handler instead of attaching handlers to all non-form elements. This handler **catches all click events**, and decides what to do. This will **speed things up on all browsers**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').focusin(function() {
        $(this).addClass('focused');
    });
    $(document).delegate("form:not(.focused) *", "click", function(){
       $('#customerdetails').focus();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IE6's javascript engine and DOM manipulation is notoriously slow at times.  For modifying large numbers of elements at a time it can be very resource intensive.  IE6 also has a tendency to block the updating of controls until some function calls have been completed (this is most apparent when updating select lists dynamically, you often have to defer execution using setTimeout).  Very annoying really.

My advice to you when using JQuery selectors is that if you are not using id selectors e.g.:

```
$("#myElement");
```

...always try and prefix any selectors with the tag type, this will speed up selection quite a lot.  When you use id selectors, jquery will use the browsers native getElementById function.  When you supply a tag name, e.g:

```
$("div.myElement");
```

jquery will use the native getElementsByTagName function to get a quicker list.  This is a lot quicker than traversing the entire DOM to try and find matching elements.

To go one stage further, try and give your selectors a context.  A context is basically a starting point from which to start searching.